# sslv3 is still showing in openssl result even after disabling from sslprotocol

Tags: tls

We are trying to disable sslv3 for poodle vulnerability.so i disabled in ssl.conf

SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1 -SSLv2 -SSLv3

and tried to connect using tlsv1 using openssl command.

openssl s_client -host localhost -port 8001 -tls1

**New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA**
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: B391D1D3B9EAC8CEF97838AA3A1D1277
    Session-ID-ctx:

I am forcing openssl to connect tlsv1 ,but it is still showing sslv3(New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA),please let me know why ot shows sslv3 even after disable in ssl.conf?

Thanks
Jay

Comment: "SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1 -SSLv2 -SSLv3" Did you just disable TLS 1.1 and 1.2!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong line.

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
```

TLSv1 and SSLv3 use many of the same ciphers.  This line is just telling you that the selected cipher is from the TLSv1/SSLv3 family.  Further down in the `openssl` output should be something like this:

```
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
```

This tells you what protocol is in use.  In my example, it's TLSv1.